# sql statement to connect two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wonder if you can help me. I need to connect two columns from 2 different tables both containing an `int data type`. foreign key are in place already.

The two table names are `email` and `labels`.

What i want to happen is when the emails are selected the `label column` from the `email table` displays the `label name` instead of the `label ID.`

what i have done is :

```
SELECT email.Labels, labels.Label_ID 
FROM email 
INNER JOIN labels 
ON email.Labels = labels.Label_Name;

Email Table:
        Message_ID
        Reciever INT
        Sender INT
        Attachments INT,
        Labels INT,
        Folders INT,
        Contents nchar(1500),
        Date datetime not null,
        Subject nchar(60),
        BCC nchar(1000),
        CC nchar(1000),
        Priority nchar(10),
        Email_Type INT not null,
        User_Account INT not null,

labels table:
        Label_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
        Label_Name nchar(60) not null,
        Date_Created DATETIME not null,
        Date_Updated DATETIME not null,
        User_Account INT not null,
```

if anyone could help I would be grateful.  Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT email.*, labels.Label_Name
FROM email 
JOIN labels ON email.labels =  labels.Label_ID ;
```

---

**see below for original answer**

---

Probably looks something like this:

```
 SELECT -- blah blah blah
 FROM -- blah blah blah
 JOIN LABEL ON EMAIL.LABELID = LABEL.ID
```

Of course this example is in the first 20 pages of any book on SQL so your question must be more complicated?  If so I believe you will have to give a lot more information about the problem.  The definition of the tables would be a good start.

Comment: i used: SELECT email.Labels, labels.Label_ID FROM email INNER JOIN labels ON email.Labels = labels.Label_Name; - however it didnt seem to work? sorry about the silly question i'm new to this

Comment: thank you very much for your help however when i view the table it still displays the ID not the label name

Comment: you are not changing the table, just running a query... the last column of the results of the query I posted will be the label name.